# In how many ways can 10 blankets be given to 3 beggars such that each recieves at least one blanket?

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

The question was to find the number of ways in which 10 identical blankets can be given to 3 beggars such that each receives at least 1 blanket. So I thought about trying the multinomial theorem...this is the first time I've tried it so I'm stuck at a point...

So $$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 10$$
Subject to the condition that :

$$1\leq x_1 \leq8$$
$$1\leq x_2 \leq8$$
$$1\leq x_3 \leq8$$

As each beggar can get at maximum 8 blankets and at minimum, 1.

So the number of ways must correspond to the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in: 
$$(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)$$

= coeff of $x^{10}$ in $x^3(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$

= coeff of $x^{10}$ in $x^3(1+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)^3$

= coeff of $x^{10}$ in $x^3(1-x^7)^3(1-x)^{-3}$

= coeff of $x^{10}$ in $x^3(1-x^{21}-3x^7(1-x^7))(1-x)^{-3}$

= coeff of $x^{10}$ in $(x^3-3x^{10})(1+\binom{3}{1}x + \binom{4}{2}x^2+...+ \binom{12}{10}x^{10})$

= $\binom{9}{7} - 3 = 33$

Is this right? From here I get the answer as $\binom{9}{7} - 3 = 33$ but the answer is stated as $36$. I don't understand where I'm making a mistake

Comment: Why did you subtract $3$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited the question to include further calculations, please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is going from

$$(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8) (x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8) \\(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)$$

to

$$x^3(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7) \\(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$$

and you should have written an $x^0$ term as in

$$x^3(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7) \\(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$$

getting you later to

coeff of $x^{10}$ in $x^3(1-x^8)^3(1-x)^{-3}$

and then giving you $36$ rather than $33$

Answer (score 1):

Try stars and bars. You have $10$ stars for the $10$ blankets:

$**********$

Now you can use $2$ bars to split this into $3$ sections. For example

$**|*******|*$

would mean beggar $1$ gets $2$ blankets, beggar $2$ gets $7$ blankets, and beggar $3$ gets $1$ blanket

Since each beggar should get at least $1$ blanket, we can't put the bars on the outside of the stars, and you also can't have the two bars between the same two stars. In other words, you need to choose $2$ out of the $9$ in-between locations, giving $9 \choose 2$ possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

While generating functions are all well and good to understand, it is unnecessary here and a more direct approach is usually preferred.

The technique of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) leads to a direct solution of $\binom{10-1}{3-1}=\binom{9}{2}=\binom{9}{7}$ outcomes where each person receives at least one item.

Comment: Yes I know the formula but I was trying to solve it in a more generalized manner

Comment: @Techie5879 "in a more generalized manner"?  How is using stars and bars not one of the most generalized manners possible for this type of problem?  Yes you can be a bit more general with generating functions by saying "No beggar is allowed exactly three blankets" and use $(x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^6+\dots)$ instead, but barring artificial problems like that stars and bars works for any number of objects to distribute and any number of bins to distribute them in with any number of minimum or maximum requirements on amount distributed to each bin...

Comment: yes you see I was trying to go with generating a function as I stated above in my question

Answer (score 0):

First give one blanket to each recipient.

Now distribute the remaining $7$ blankets to $3$ recipients without constraints:  $36$

If one person gets $7$ (additional) and the others get none, there are $3$ ways to do that.  And likewise for the following distributions:

- $700$, $3$ ways
- $610$, $6$ ways
- $520$, $6$ ways
- $511$, $3$ ways
- $430$, $6$ ways
- $421$, $6$ ways
- $331$, $3$ ways
- $322$, $3$ ways (thanks @JMoravitz)

Total = $36$ ways

Comment: Simple typo... fixed within 20 seconds.

Comment: You missed 322 as a possibility.  At least now you have an explanation to match your attempt... This is still far too much brute force than is necessary for a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a blanket to each one and  and use stars and bars with remaining $7$ blanket.

You only need two bars with seven stars so the answer is $\binom {9}{2} =36$